# Edit root files from CD Card, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, root

So, I heard that it's  possible to edit root files on Linux but if I trying to save the file I get this message:

**They do not have the necessary authorisations to store the file. Please, check whether you have properly given the place, and try it once more.**

So, how can I change root user?

Comment: Look up `sudo`.

Comment: Your question pops up again. Does the answer help you?

Comment: Do you mean SD card, as in "secure digital"? CD means "compact disk".

Answer (score 1):

To get root access you can prefix the commands with `sudo`, for example:

```
rpi ~$ sudo editor /etc/issue
```

To get permanent root rights for all following commands you can use:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
root@rpi ~# editor /etc/issue
root@rpi ~# exit
rpi ~$
```

You should use this mode with care and leave it as soon as possible with `exit`. Unix isn't made to work interactive as root.